# Accidently Removed the PostgreSql Directory

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

I have installed Odoo 9.0-20160923 openerp on my windows, for some reason i didn't want this version so i uninstalled it successfully from Program and Features and then hard delete its respective directory from C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20160923 which accidentally removed the PostgreSql Directory too which was located in it now i can't manage to re-install the PostgreSQL and also not able to completely remove PostgreSql from my PC. Kindly suggest appropriate solution to this so i can manage to completely remove the PostgreSQL from my PC and re-install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, by getting the PostgreSQL setup and runs the uninstall process which removes all the files then i re-install it. Now every thing is working fine.